# Phoenix remove [debug] logging

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

When running a phoenix server, I am getting `[debug]` logs which I would like to not have (the logs in blue).

[image]

How can I alter my `config` to get rid of these

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the log level in `dev` to be higher than `debug` which will make Logger not print any `debug` messages. The level [just above `debug` is `info`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-levels). You can set that by adding this to `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :logger, level: :info
```

If you already have a `config :logger` line, you can just add `level: :info` at the end of it. You will have to restart your application for this to take effect.