# Toggle Phoenix.Controller Level ExAdmin

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir/Phoenix & I'm using ex_admin for our back office, I would like to toggle the Phoenix.

Controller log_level to `info`. Its working fine for my own web module but I can't figure out a way to override it in the deps and force it to `info` instead of `debug`.

[web.ex Source Code](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin/blob/master/web/web.ex#L16)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phoenix remove \[debug\] logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004234/phoenix-remove-debug-logging)

Comment: I don't want to ignore those log lines, I want to change their log level